# I am getting No module named 'oauth2._compat'

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0

I had problems with importing oauth2 package. In in the init.py file there is a problem with this line getting executed, `from ._compat import PY3` . I don't know why installing and running oauth2 is such a mess

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:
`from oauth2._compat import PY3`
the error you were getting suggests that you were trying to import __main__.compat instead of oauth2._compat